# Is there services helping to fund a project selling merch?

Tags: monetization

We're trying to raise some fund for our Open Source project.

There's a lot of companies out there selling t-shirts and stickers with Open Source projects, but they don't give a share of the profits to those projects.

I was wondering if there was any initiative out there selling merchandise who're giving a part of the profits back to the projects?

Comment: Why do you think those projects don't get money from t-shirt sales? For example, Canonical certainly makes money [selling t-shirts from their store](http://askubuntu.com/q/21730/205891).

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying they don't. I'm looking for a company using a project brand to sell merchandise and give a part of the profit back to the project. I was pointing at companies selling merchandises with OSS logo without giving anything back as example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out [DevSwag](http://devswag.com/) was offering a [service to help fund Open Source project](http://devswag.com/pages/selling-on-devswag) by selling merch.

Extract from their website:

> DevSwag is designed to help projects get their materials out there. While it isn't a profit-source for Tilde (even if sales would go gangbusters, we're still only talking about selling stickers and tshirts here :p), it does have costs, so we split revenues with the projects.

The Project needs to invest the initial fund to buy the product. So it requires some initial investment.